# how to convert pdf scanned image to high resolution tiff with best for ocr?

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, tiff

I convert pdf to tiff image with image magick,
from 500kb to 4.6mb filesize.

The problem is result of that convertion in tiff image not good. Some text hard to read.

this is my simple command in cli

```
convert \
pph.pdf \
pph-psd.tiff
```

PDF Scanned Image :
[image: PDF Scanned Image]

Tiff Image : 
[image: TIFF IMAGE]

why is this happend and how to convert pdf scanned image to high resolution tiff with best for ocr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has happened because ImageMagick is a raster image processor and it has rasterised your PDF using its default 72dpi grid - which is too coarse for your needs. You need to set a higher density before rasterising:

```
convert -density 288 input.pdf -compress lzw result.tiff
```

---

You may be better off installing Poppler tools and using its `pdfimages` tool to extract the images.

Answer (score -2):

If you want you can try Coolutils TotalPDFConverter which worked for me.